# push JSON array into key value pair of an array

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON array like below:

```
rows =[
        {
            "ID":132,
            "TITLE":"Questions one",
            "DESCRIPTION":"Questions one DESCRIPTION",
            "EXPERT_RATING":3,
            "DURATION":15,
            "SOURCE_URL":"http://testing.com",
            "COMMENT":null,
            "UserID": 1214
        },
        {
            "ID":137,
            "TITLE":"Questions two",
            "DESCRIPTION":"Questions two description",
            "EXPERT_RATING":3,
            "DURATION":15,
            "SOURCE_URL":"http://question2.com",
            "COMMENT":null,
            "UserID": 1214
        }
    ]
```

Now, I want to push it into an array, so it should look like below:

```
res[132] = ['Questions one', 'Questions one DESCRIPTION', 3, 15, 'http://testing.com', null, 1214]
res[137] = ['Questions two', 'Questions two DESCRIPTION', 3, 15, 'http://question2.co', null,1214]
```

I have tried the following cod, but is showing lot of null records

```
rows.forEach(function(key){

                recJson[key.ID] = [key.TITLE, key.DESCRIPTION, key.EXPERT_RATING, key.DURATION, key.SOURCE_URL, key.COACHING_TIPS, key.MGR_COMMENT, key.UserID]             
            });

console.log(recJson);
```

Tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest you using objects instead of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my approach.

```js
var rows = [{
  "ID": 132,
  "TITLE": "Questions one",
  "DESCRIPTION": "Questions one DESCRIPTION",
  "EXPERT_RATING": 3,
  "DURATION": 15,
  "SOURCE_URL": "http://testing.com",
  "COMMENT": null
 },
 {
  "ID": 137,
  "RTITLE": "Questions two",
  "DESCRIPTION": "Questions two description",
  "EXPERT_RATING": 3,
  "DURATION": 15,
  "SOURCE_URL": "http://question2.com",
  "COMMENT": null
 },
 {
  "ID": 137,
  "RTITLE": "Questions three",
  "DESCRIPTION": "Questions three description",
  "EXPERT_RATING": 3,
  "DURATION": 15,
  "SOURCE_URL": "http://question3.com",
  "COMMENT": null
 },
 {
  "ID": 137,
  "RTITLE": "Questions four",
  "DESCRIPTION": "Questions four description",
  "EXPERT_RATING": 3,
  "DURATION": 15,
  "SOURCE_URL": "http://question4.com",
  "COMMENT": null
 }
];
var arr = rows.map(ar => Object.values(ar));
var obj = {};
arr.map(ar => {
 var id = ar[0];
 ar.splice(0, 1);
 //if duplicate key occures creating a nested array.
 if (obj.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj[id][0])) {
   obj[id].push(ar);
  } else {
   obj[id] = [obj[id], ar];
  }
 } else {
  obj[id] = ar;
 }
});

console.log(obj);
```

*Edited*

Updated for duplicate key occurrence.

Comment: Actually, In my result set I have total 73 records, when I am using your solution using Object.values, it is removing some and it is outputting only 33 records. Why is it hapening? Is there a way where I can get all the 73 records in the above format with key and values?

Comment: is that all the 73 records are in the same structure? I mean, Is there any nested objects or array inside that? @sony

Comment: All the records are in the same structure, but there will be duplicate keys with different values, those keys should not be eliminated while outputting

Comment: For duplicate keys do you want nested array? @sony

Comment: like this.
`{"137": [[
    "Questions two",
    "Questions two description",
    3,
    15,
    "http://question2.com",
    null
  ],[
   "Questions three",
    "Questions three description",
    3,
    15,
    "http://question3.com",
    null
]]}`

Comment: You are welcome. You can support me by upvoting my correct answers. :) @sony

Answer (score 2):

If you're using that code directly, you have an inconsistency or typo. Your dataset seems to be interchanging between TITLE and RTITLE. If your data is truly like that, you can indiscriminately push all the values of each entry to an array using a `reduce` function and `Object.values`:

```
rows.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr["ID"]] = Object.values(curr);
  return acc;
}, {})
```

Which will result in this:

```
{
  132: [132, "Questions one", "Questions one DESCRIPTION", 3, 15, "http://testing.com", null]
  137: (7) [137, "Questions two", "Questions two description", 3, 15, "http://question2.com", null]
}
```

This should give you what you'd like.

Comment: it is giving an empty array as output.

Answer (score 0):

The bit missing from your code, is:

```
var recJson = [];
```

which means you're adding an entry to a javascript array *by index*, so, in order for javascript to add index `132`, it has to add indices `0`-`131` first - so you get a lot of null/undefineds.

You could instead push each entry to the array, but this would not let you access them by ID - so better to use an object

```
var recJson = {};
```

which will add your values as properties.

```js
rows = [{
    "ID": 132,
    "TITLE": "Questions one",
    "DESCRIPTION": "Questions one DESCRIPTION",
    "EXPERT_RATING": 3,
    "DURATION": 15,
    "SOURCE_URL": "http://testing.com",
    "COMMENT": null
  },
  {
    "ID": 137,
    "RTITLE": "Questions two",
    "DESCRIPTION": "Questions two description",
    "EXPERT_RATING": 3,
    "DURATION": 15,
    "SOURCE_URL": "http://question2.com",
    "COMMENT": null
  }
]


var recJson = {};
rows.forEach(function(key) {
  recJson[key.ID] = [key.RTITLE, key.DESCRIPTION, key.EXPERT_RATING, key.DURATION, key.SOURCE_URL, key.COACHING_TIPS, key.MGR_COMMENT, key.ATTUID];
});

console.log(recJson);
```

Comment: This is not a good idea because for getting any element with specific idea you will need to iterate through whose array.

Comment: @MaheerAli I was just updating for that :)  It's a viable option that depends on how OP want's to access the values.  As OP is adding by key, it's a safe assumption they want to access by key.

Comment: @freedomn-m, I want the output to be mapped with key's as like my above given result... {
  132: [132, "Questions one", "Questions one DESCRIPTION", 3, 15, "http://testing.com", null]
  137: (7) [137, "Questions two", "Questions two description", 3, 15, "http://question2.com", null]
}

Answer (score 0):

- First, you need to make sure your array is appropriately sized for those indices.
- Next, you need some way to get the order of the fields. (Make sure your field name are consistent)
- Last, just reduce the fields for each row to grab the appropriate value.

```js
let rows = [{
  "ID": 132,
  "TITLE": "Questions one",
  "DESCRIPTION": "Questions one DESCRIPTION",
  "EXPERT_RATING": 3,
  "DURATION": 15,
  "SOURCE_URL": "http://testing.com",
  "COMMENT": null
}, {
  "ID": 137,
  "RTITLE": "Questions two",
  "DESCRIPTION": "Questions two description",
  "EXPERT_RATING": 3,
  "DURATION": 15,
  "SOURCE_URL": "http://question2.com",
  "COMMENT": null
}];

let res = new Array(138);
let fields = [ 'RTITLE', 'DESCRIPTION', 'EXPERT_RATING', 'DURATION', 'SOURCE_URL', 'COMMENT' ];

rows.forEach(row => {
  res[row.ID] = fields.reduce((arr, field) => arr.concat(row[field]), []);
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

As others have suggested, maybe an object would be better.

```js
rows.reduce((obj, row) => {
  return Object.assign(obj, { [row.ID] : fields.reduce((arr, field) => {
    return arr.concat(row[field]);
  }, []) })
}, res);
```

```js
let rows = [{
  "ID": 132,
  "TITLE": "Questions one",
  "DESCRIPTION": "Questions one DESCRIPTION",
  "EXPERT_RATING": 3,
  "DURATION": 15,
  "SOURCE_URL": "http://testing.com",
  "COMMENT": null
}, {
  "ID": 137,
  "RTITLE": "Questions two",
  "DESCRIPTION": "Questions two description",
  "EXPERT_RATING": 3,
  "DURATION": 15,
  "SOURCE_URL": "http://question2.com",
  "COMMENT": null
}];

let res = {};
let fields = [ 'RTITLE', 'DESCRIPTION', 'EXPERT_RATING', 'DURATION', 'SOURCE_URL', 'COMMENT' ];

rows.reduce((obj, row) => Object.assign(obj, { [row.ID] : fields.reduce((arr, field) => arr.concat(row[field]), []) }), res);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: OPs issue is that there are 138 `undefined` before the first value

Comment: Which is why I noted that the array needs to be appropriately sized.

Comment: ? Your first snippet, "appropriately sized", shows 138 `undefined`.  So how does that fix anything vs allowing js to expand the array automatically?

Comment: Just to make sure indexing works as intended. I am not sure what `res` looks like or how it is populated, but is beyond the scope of the question as OP did not present these facts.

Comment: Here, the fields are dynamic and these should not be hard-coded in the array logic... @Mr.Polywhirl

Comment: @sony But the order of object properties are not guaranteed. You need to specify order if you’re throwing values into an array.

Comment: is there any better solution other than hard-coding field names?

Comment: @sony What is `res` being used for? Is this a CSV file?

Comment: No, It is used to populate data in website

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use it, I suggest to use a [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in this case to hold your new structure. Creating an [array with holes is not a good idea](https://dev.to/voodooattack/the-holey-array-problem-3pg8). Alternatively you can use an object, where the `keys` are the `ids` and the `values` the desired array.

This will be the `Map` solution:

```js
const rows = [
  {
    "ID":132,
    "TITLE":"Questions one",
    "DESCRIPTION":"Questions one DESCRIPTION",
    "EXPERT_RATING":3,
    "DURATION":15,
    "SOURCE_URL":"http://testing.com",
    "COMMENT":null
  },
  {
    "ID":137,
    "RTITLE":"Questions two",
    "DESCRIPTION":"Questions two description",
    "EXPERT_RATING":3,
    "DURATION":15,
    "SOURCE_URL":"http://question2.com",
    "COMMENT":null
   }
];

let myMap = rows.reduce((acc, o) =>
{
    acc.set(o.ID, [
        o.hasOwnProperty("TITLE") ? o.TITLE : o.RTITLE,
        o.DESCRIPTION,
        o.EXPERT_RATING,
        o.DURATION,
        o.SOURCE_URL,
        o.COMMENT
    ]);
    return acc;
}, new Map());

console.log("Data for id 132:", myMap.get(132));
console.log("Data for id 137:", myMap.get(137));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Note the only way to ensure the resulting array will be ordered as you want is to enumerate all properties in the order you want. You can't trust on `Object.values()` to give you all arrays with the same order of keys. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) about this.